# RoR, RSpec: want to verify that each link on a page can be serviced

Tags: rspec, nokogiri, webrat, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm beefing up RSpec tests on my RoR app.  I'd like a simple way to verify that clicking on each link on a page is properly handled, i.e. generates a recognized route to a controller, and has a method in the controller to service it.

I can write specific tests for each page, but it would be preferable to have an RSpec helper function find all the links on a page automagically and verify each one.  FWIW, it's safe to assume that all links are in my domain (there are no links to external sites).

Rather than bloat this question by enumerating all the things I've tried, I'll just ask: how would you do it?  Seems like a common and useful function.

- ff

Answer (score 1):

I'd use Capybara prob...

```
 1. make list of  pages
 2. For each page
 3.     Visit page
 4.     get all links using xpath (included in capybaara)
 5.     For each link
 6.          do a Rspec test get url; response.should be_ok
```

Comment: i already have nokogiri -- do I really need Capybara just to get the links on a page?

Comment: no, probably not..  I just say capybara since its already integrated into RSpec and would probably lower the WTF factor.  That said, Capybara  uses Nokogiri internally, but I don't know off the top of my head how directly grabbing a link with Nokogiri and integrating it with Rspec would work.  It might be transparent, i've  just never tried it..so I can't say

Comment: Let me add to my original answer, perhaps you could use a sitemap gem to make a list of all the pages in your app, and make it easier to get to step 1

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing belongs in an integration test, which you could write either in RSpec or Cucumber. Testing a link on it's own is of limited value - it will tell you if the link is broken, but it won't tell you if the link is pointing to the wrong place.

In Cucumber, you could write something like:

```
Given I am on the home page
When I follow "Buy Stuff"
Then I should be on the shopping page
```

Comment: agreed that this is integration testing.  disagreed that such is of limited value: it will immediately highlight missing routes, missing static pages, etc. the crux of my question is how to automatically get all the links on a page, click on each one and make sure that none result in an error.